# get RETURNING after updating a record in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, arel

how to make this query in activerecord:

```
UPDATE table_name SET column = 'value' WHERE id = 123 RETURNING other_column
```

I tried `update_all` but it returns number of changed records, `update_atributes` which returns true/false, and `update` which returns the whole object.

In rails it should look like this (pseudo-code):

```
other_column = TableName.where(:id => 123).update_attributes(:column => 'value').returning(:other_column)
puts other_column
```

Comment: Please elaborate your question with the code you implemented. (Model, controller etc.)

Answer (score 2):

```
result_sets = Model.connection.execute("UPDATE table_name SET column = 'value' WHERE id = 123 RETURNING other_column")
result_sets.each do |result|
  p result[:other_column]
end
```

If you just want to update a single record with id 123, why can't you do this?

```
   TableName.update(123, :column => 'value').other_column
```

Comment: If you're going to use `connection.execute`, you'll have to deal with be careful with quoting/escaping the values in the SQL.

Comment: `connection.execute` will bypass rails validations, and `update` will generate 2 queries: `select`, `update`. 
I need just one query.